# Oracle Transaction Commit

Tags: oracle, spring-transactions

Lets say I have a function which carries out a lot of CRUD operations, and also assume that this function is going to get executed without any exception (100% success). Is it better to have a transaction for the entire function or transaction commits for each CRUD operation. Basically, I wanted to know whether using many transaction commits has an impact on the memory and time consumption while executing the function which has a lot of CRUD operations.

Answer (score 2):

Transaction boundaries should be defined by your business logic.

If your application has 100 CRUD operations to do, and each is completely independent of the others, maybe a commit after each is appropriate.  Think about this: is it OK for a user running a report against your database to see only half of the CRUD operations?

A **transaction** is a set of updates that must all happen together or not at all, because a partial transaction would represent an inconsistent or inaccurate state.

Commit at the end of every transaction - that's it.  No more, no less.  It's not about performance, releasing locks, or managing server resources.  Those are all real technical issues, but you don't solve them by committing halfway through a logical unit of work.  Commit frequency is not a valid "tuning trick".

#### EDIT

To answer your actual question:

> Basically, I wanted to know whether using many transaction commits has an impact on the memory and time consumption while executing the function which has a lot of CRUD operations.

Committing frequently will actually slow you down.  Every time you do a regular commit, Oracle has to make sure that anything in the redo log buffers is flushed to disk, and your `COMMIT` will wait for the that process to complete.

Also, there is little or no memory savings in frequent commits.  Almost all your transaction's work and any held locks are written to redo log buffers and/or database block buffers in memory.  Oracle will flush both of those to disk in background as often as it needs to in order to manage memory.  Yes, that's right -- your dirty, uncommitted database blocks can be written to disk.  No commit necessary.

The only resource that a really huge transaction can blow out is UNDO space.  But, again, you don't fix that problem by committing half way through a logical unit of work.  If your logical unit of work is really that huge, size your database with an appropriate amount of UNDO space.

Comment: I completely agree with you. But for a job, that can start again from the point where it is stopped, we don't have to come from the beginning everytime if there is an exception in the middle right ?. But I'm concerned about the memory and time usage.

Comment: If it is OK for only 50 of your 100 CRUD operations to be committed and visible in your application, on reports, etc, then it sounds like you have 100 transactions.  If it's NOT OK, then it sounds like you have _one_ transaction and, in that case, have little choice but to restart from the beginning every time there is an exception in the middle.  This is one reason why people stage things.  Say you're loading a file and the whole file is one transaction.  If you stage it, you can commit each CRUD to the staging table, and then update the real table as a single transaction.

Comment: now I have just one transaction on the higher level. The reason I keep stressing on the time is because one of the deletes takes a longer time and it is getting timed out. I like to split the transaction and see whether that would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My response is "it depends."  Does the transaction involve data in only one table or several?  Are you performing inserts, updates, or deletes.  With an INSERT no other session can see your data till it is committed so technically no rush.  However if you update a row on a table where the exact same row may need to be updated by another session in short order you do not want to hold the row for any longer than absolutely necessary.  What constitutes a logic unit of work, how much UNDO the table and index changes involved consume, and concurrent DML demand for the same rows all come into play when choosing the commit frequency.

Comment: All operations are deletes, and from different tables. I also follow an order to execute these deletes.

Comment: Popeye, if there are parent child relationships between rows then I expect you delete the parent and children in the same transaction to maintain data consistency in the event of process interruption.